# Connect ViewModel to Model

Tags: c#, mvvm, model, viewmodel

I'm working on an application and spent quite some time finding a solution for the following problem. I've tried several things but I'm not sure what's the best approach to solve it.

I've got a setup of a View, ViewModel and a Model. The ViewModel contains a collection of models of which the user can select a specific model (the collection can be empty which makes the selected model null).

The View consists of a Combobox which allows the user to select a model out of a collection of models. The selected model will then be displayed in the view (with various controls such as treeviews, labels, ...).

This is the Model (I will keep it simple for the sake of explanation):

```
public Model {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Model(_id, _name) {
        id = _id;
        name = _name;
    }

    public int ID {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public String Name {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

And the ViewModel:

```
public ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private ObservableCollection<Model> models = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
    private Model selectedModel;

    public ViewModel() { }

    public Model SelectedModel {
        get { return selectedModel; }
        set { 
            selectedModel = value; 
            NotifyChanged("SelectedModel");   
        }
    }
    public Model ModelCellection {
        get { return models; }
        set { 
            models = value; 
            NotifyChanged("ModelCellection");   
        }
    }

    public void addModel(Model newModel) {
        models.Add(newModel);
    }

    //variant A
    public int ID {
        get { return (selectedModel == null) ? 0 : selectedModel.ID; }
        set {
            if(selectedModel == null)
                return; 
            selectedModel.ID = value; 
            NotifyChanged("ID");   
        }
    }
    public String Name {
        get { return (selectedModel == null) ? 0 : selectedModel.Name; }
        set {
            if(selectedModel == null)
                return; 
            selectedModel.Name = value; 
            NotifyChanged("Name");   
        }
    }

    //variant B (the attributes of the model will be copied when the selected model changes)
    public void changeSelectedModel(Model newSelectedModel) {
        Name = newSelectedModel.Name;
        Id = newSelectedModel.Id;
    }
    private int id = 0;
    private String name = String.Empty;
    public int ID {
        get { return id; }
        set {
            id = value; 
            NotifyChanged("ID");   
        }
    }
    public String Name {
        get { return name; }
        set {
            name = value; 
            NotifyChanged("Name");   
        }
    }
}
```

My Question is pretty simple: How do I access the relevant public properties of the Model via the ViewModel?

The solutions I've tried so far are:

- Variant A: Just change the selected model and use proxy properties to access the properties of the model (problem: The view doesn't get updated when the selected model changes because the Name and Id properties of the ViewModel don't raise a PropertyChanged event)
- Variant B: Copy the relevant properties of the model when the selected model is changed (problem: I have to copy the properties of the model)

After talking to some guys in the wpf chat I switched from variant B to variant A but I don't know how to solve the problem of updating the view when the selected model changes? Or would you rather suggest to use a completely different approach to solve this?

Comment: I'd go for variant C: create a `ViewModelItem` that will correspond to `Model` as far as properties go, but will also handle property notification, validation etc. Then, in the 'main' `ViewModel` use the collection of said ViewModelItems. You can use a tool like ValueInjecter or AutoMapper to map between models and view models...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't know how to solve the problem of updating the view when the selected model changes?

Just raise `PropertyChanged` event in your `SelectedModel` definition

```
public Model SelectedModel {
        get { return selectedModel; }
        set { 
            selectedModel = value; 
            NotifyChanged("SelectedModel");   
            NotifyChanged("ID");
            NotifyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this - thanks :). Is this approach "state of the art" to access the models properties?

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your Model.
Your code look like.

Your Model.cs

```
public Model:INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
private int id;
private String name;

public Model(_id, _name) 
  {
    id = _id;
    name = _name;
   }

public int ID {
    get { return id; }
    set { id = value;  NotifyChanged("ID");}
    }
public String Name
   {
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value;  NotifyChanged("Name");}
   }
}
```

Your ViewModel.cs

```
 public ViewModel 
 {
  private ObservableCollection<Model> models = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
  private Model selectedModel;

  public ViewModel() { }

  private Model _SelectedModel ;
  public Model SelectedModel 
  {
    get { return _SelectedModel??(_SelectedModel=new SelectedModel());}
    set { _SelectedModel  = value;}
   }
 }
```

If property has been Changed it will aromatically Notify because in the ViewModel Model object is present.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your property like

```
public void changeSelectedModel(Model newSelectedModel) 
 {
    SelectedModel.Name = newSelectedModel.Name;
    SelectedModel.Id = newSelectedModel.Id;
 }
```

and it will Notify.